# circular dependency

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any ROS tools to help me track down circular dependencies between my ROS nodes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9374/circular-dependency/) by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 794 on 2011-03-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on 2011-03-11**:
As a follow up, I thought i had a circular dependency in my packages because when i call rosmake with a few of my stacks, i see this message: [rospack] woah! expanding the dependency tree made it blow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that dependencies are between *packages* or *stacks*, not *nodes*.

To list the dependencies of a package named `foo`:

```
$ rospack depends foo
```

To list the packages that depend on `foo` (directly or indirectly):

```
$ rospack depends-on foo
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2